# How to use Launchd to run applescript when a music file is opened?

Tags: macos, applescript, itunes

I am having issues with my "Automatically Add to iTunes". As a result, I am trying to make an Applescript that will be stored on my USB, and when I click on a certain Music File, I want it to launch an applescript.

I did some research, and everyone keeps telling me about Launchd. How would I use this command to run an applescript saved as .app? I want to store this Music File and the Applescript on my USB, because I have multiple computers. Can I get it to run as soon as I open a specified music file? Thank you.

Comment: `launchd` can be used to detect when a (USB) volume is mounted or unmounted, practically it's monitoring the folder `/Volumes`. The attached script must be located of the target computer.

Comment: then how would I have a script detect when a music file is opened?

Comment: In your case I'd recommend to create a script / app and drag it into the toolbar of a Finder window next to the search field. Then you can select a file and click on the script to run it. This works in any Finder window. `launchd` is not needed.

Comment: all i want to do is click on a applesctipt .app, have it run a script and play a music file. I feel like I should be able to do this with bundling. I already asked this problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40347342/how-would-i-use-bundling-to-have-an-applescript-act-like-a-music-file

Comment: I wrote an answer in the linked topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out a way to do what I wanted, which was to somehow play a music file from inside the application. All I did was use the idea of resources because it can reference itself without having to rely on a file stored somewhere else on the system. Here's a link to essentially what I did: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/157724/applescript-path-to-files-in-applications-resources

in short, I contained the music file within the app itself and played it when it was needed.